# Cannot catch instantiations errors with Serilog and .Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-5.0, serilog-sinks-file

I have a .Net Core 5 app with Serilog. I am testing error logging and I have a class that cannot be instantiated because I commented out some services in the DI registration.
This is my Program.cs file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .Enrich.FromLogContext()
           .WriteTo.File("Logs/Startup.txt", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
           .CreateLogger();
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

In the `Startup.txt` file I am only seeing the `Information` and not the errors. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial logger is using `File()` but you later call `UseSerilog(callback)` which will overwrite it with whatever is in the configuration file.

`CreateBootstrapLogger()` sorts all of this out by allowing the startup and later application logs to be merged:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.File("Logs/Log.txt")  // <-- No longer need a separate startup log
       .CreateBootstrapLogger();  // <-- Change this line

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting up");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        return 1;  // <-- Change this line
    }
    finally  // <-- Add this block
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    return 0;  // <-- Add this line
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
            .WriteTo.File("Logs/Log.txt") // <-- Add this line
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

If you really don't want startup and regular log events in the same sinks, you can initialize a separate logger for start-up instead:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    using var startup = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.File("Logs/Startup.txt")
       .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        startup.Information("Starting up");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        startup.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        return 1;  // <-- Change this line
    }

    return 0;  // <-- Add this line
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

(I still also suggest avoiding `Environment.Exit()` when possible.)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing you're missing is a `Log.CloseAndFlush()` in a try/finally
eta: NB The `Environment.Exit()` would make that irrelevant - that's the first thing to fix.

There's good writeups on how to do this correctly end to end by Nick:

- https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3
- https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger/

Comment: Did not fixed the problem.

Comment: OK, please update the question to show your latest code so someone else can help (the Environment.Exit is still v suspicious to me)